# Detecting repeated groups of lines

Tags: algorithm, compression

I've got several megabytes of data like this:

```
11  2  1
 4  3  1
11  2  1
 4  3  1
11  2  1
 4  3  1
18  3  2
```

I'd like to compress it by adding lines saying "previous n lines repeated m times." The algorithm should read lines and delay printing them out until finding the longest possible m*n, but can assume n<=10. What would be the best way to do this?

I was thinking of just keeping 10 arrays of 1..10 previous lines with repeat counters, rotating the array contents as new lines come in and printing the above message when a newly read line didn't match the oldest entry in any of the arrays, and at least one of the arrays is filled with repeats.

Comment: can you elaborate on the technology you are using and the purpose? if you just wanto to compress, you can use the zip algorithms, no?

Comment: I want the data to remain human readable. Linux syslog compresses individual repeated lines that way but I'd like also repeats of groups of 2-10 lines compressed in the same way.

Comment: The compression could be done in awk, perl or C for example. Also, there's little correlation in the data other than the repeats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"copy previous n lines repeated m times" is a limited version of "copy k lines starting from j lines back".  The first one is the second one with k = n * m and j = n.  The more general k,j version is LZ77.  (Though normally it's bytes and not lines.)

LZ77 algorithms would work very well for this.  The hash table approach used by gzip, zlib, etc., is fast and easy to code.  First, define the minimum value of k (mink) that you would consider worthwhile, and define how far back you want to look for matches, i.e. the maximum value of j (maxj).  Then construct a sliding window of maxj lines to search in.

As each line comes in, update a hash that depends only on the last mink lines.  Look in the hash table for the last line that matches that hash, and then compare your lines directly with what's in the sliding window there until they don't match.  Then if the resulting length is mink or more, you have a match, which is composed of a length and a distance (k and j).

Use lazy-matching, where you defer the emission of a match until you process the next line, which may give a longer match.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know LZ77 doesn't build a dictionary like LZW. Fits my purpose perfectly. 200k lines of input was summarized into 30k.

Answer (score 1):

zip algorithms can keep the data readable. They just create dictionaries of repeating elements (look at [lempel - ziv](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LZ77) for example). 
I think the algorithm the way you describe it might be problematic. Your second line differs from your first line, so how will you know you're supposed to treat them as one group? when will you limit the group, and start a new one?
How can you tell that

```
11 2 1
4 3 1
```

really belong to the same group?

I think lempel ziv can solve it for you, with a dictionary including all the possible sub-sets and the number of their occurences. 
In your dictionary you will have sub sets such as

```
11 2 1
4 3 1
11 2 1
```

but if you somehow know the repeating lines will come in pairs or triplets, you can limit the checked subset in algorithm, and keep the sub sets in the dictionary in your expected length.

This way eventually your dictionary will look like this:

```
key          : count
11 2 1       : 3
4  3 1       : 3
11 2 1, 4 3 1: 3
18 3 2       : 1
```

Of course, it needs more tweaking but i think this algorithm should be the general direction

Comment: Lempel-Ziv seems to do a slightly different thing, if we had for example a pattern AABAAB according to that Wikipedia link it would encode into (0,A), (1,A), (2,B), (3,0) and I'd want it to output AAB,2. Problem is after seeing the first AA it still shouldn't output anything... Also, after every reported repeated group of lines the dictionary should become empty.

Comment: if you know you always have pairs or triplets of lines that you care for, then use every 2 or 3 lines as input for the algorith. Here, for example, you'd have to pass AAB not A/AB. your case seems to simplify the algorithm, assuming you know the repeating lines come in finite known groups.

Comment: The repeated section size varies within the file and is typically 1-4 lines long.

Answer (score 0):

If you think of your file as a long string, then I think that your problem consists in finding the [longest repeated substring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_repeated_substring_problem)